# How to fix 0 value inserted in the database in the second request on Ajax?

Tags: jquery, mysql, laravel

I have problem regarding inserting the last insert ID in the second request of Ajax, when I view the column all inserted items are `0` value. So now I want to insert each table row with having own unique ID

**I have two table:**

1. `wish_list_menu_order`
2. `wish_list_menu_belong_condiments`

The first insert was on `wish_list_menu_order`, so in the success function of first insert, I have second request which the url was `wish_list_menu_belong_condiments`.

**First Request:**

```
public function insert_wish_list_menu_order(Request $request)
{
    $customer_id = $request->get('customer_id');
    $append_customer_noun_order = $request->get('append_customer_noun_order');
    $append_customer_noun_order_price = $request->get('append_customer_noun_order_price');
    $now = new DateTime();

    for ($count = 0; $count < count($append_customer_noun_order); $count++) {

        DB::insert('INSERT INTO wish_list_menu_order (customer_id,wish_list_menu_name,wish_list_total_price,wish_created_at) 
        VALUES(?,?,?,?) ', [

            $customer_id,
            $append_customer_noun_order[$count],
            $append_customer_noun_order_price[$count],
            $now,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Second Request:**

```
public function insert_wish_list_menu_belong_condiments(Request $request)
{
    $Qty = $request->get('Qty');
    $Item = $request->get('Item');
    $Cost = $request->get('Cost');

    $now = new DateTime();

    $last_id_insert = DB::select('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as id FROM wish_list_menu_order');

    foreach ($last_id_insert as $result) {
        $id_last_inserted = $result->id;
    }

    for ($count = 0; $count < count($Item); $count++) {

        DB::insert('INSERT INTO wish_list_menu_belong_condiments (wish_menu_id,belong_condi_name,belong_condi_qty,belong_condi_price,belong_condi_created) 
        VALUES(?,?,?,?,?) ', [

            $id_last_inserted,
            $Item[$count],
            $Qty[$count],
            $Cost[$count],
            $now,
        ]);
    }

    return response()->json('Successfully Inserted');
}
```

**My Ajax:**

```
$('button#add_to_cart').on('click', function () {

    var customer_id = $('#hidden_customer_id').val();

    var parent_item = [];
    var parent_amount = [];

    //child
    var child_item = [];
    var child_quantity = [];
    var child_amount = [];

    //this is for parent item and amount
    $('#noun_chaining_order').find('tr.condimentParent td.parent_item').each(function () {
        parent_item.push($(this).text());
    });

    $('#noun_chaining_order').find('tr.condimentParent td.total').each(function () {
        parent_amount.push($(this).text());
    });

    //end

    //this is for child item,amount and quantity
    $('#noun_chaining_order').find('tr.editCondiments td.child_item').each(function () {
        child_item.push($(this).text())
    });

    $('#noun_chaining_order').find('tr.editCondiments td.total').each(function () {
        child_amount.push($(this).text());
    });

    $('#noun_chaining_order').find('tr.editCondiments td.condiments_order_quantity').each(function () {
        child_quantity.push($(this).text());
    });

    $.ajax({

        url: '/insert_wish_list_menu_order',
        type: 'post',

        data: {
            customer_id: customer_id,
            append_customer_noun_order: parent_item,
            append_customer_noun_order_price: parent_amount,
            Qty: child_quantity,
            Item: child_item,
            Cost: child_amount
        },

        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);

            $.ajax({

                url: '/insert_wish_list_menu_belong_condiments',
                type: 'post',

                data: {
                    Qty: child_quantity,
                    Item: child_item,
                    Cost: child_amount
                },

                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                },

                error: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

**This is how I append the menu items in the table.**

```
$("tr#productClicked").click(function () {

      var menu_name = $(this).closest("tr").find(".menu_name").text();
      var menu_price = $(this).closest("tr").find(".menu_price").text();
      var chain_id =  $(this).closest("tr").find(".chain_id").text();
      var menu_image = $(this).closest("tr").find(".menu_image").attr('src');
      var menu_cat_id =  $(this).closest("tr").find(".menu_id").text();
      var customer_id = $('#hidden_customer_id').val();

      if(chain_id == 0)
      {
         $("tbody#tbody_noun_chaining_order").
          append("<tr class='condimentParent' style='background-color:'black !important',color:'white !important' '>\
          <td></td><td class='parent_item'>"+menu_name+"</td><td class='total'>"+menu_price+"</td>\
          <td><button class='removeorderWithOutCondi btn btn-danger form-control'>\
          <i class='far fa-trash-alt'></i></button></td></tr>");

          //computation of total click without chain
          var sum_sub_total_price = 0;
          $('td.total').each(function () {
            sum_sub_total_price += parseFloat($(this).text());
          });
          var with_decimal_subprice = parseFloat(sum_sub_total_price).toFixed(2);
          $('.append_customer_noun_order_price').text(with_decimal_subprice);
      }
      else
      {
          $("tbody#tbody_noun_chaining_order").
          append("<tr class='condimentParent' style='background-color:'black !important',color:'white !important' '>\
          <td></td><td class='parent_item'>"+menu_name+"</td><td class='total'>"+menu_price+"</td>\
          <td><button class='removeorderWithOutCondi btn btn-danger form-control'>\
          <i class='far fa-trash-alt'></i></button></td></tr>");

          //after displaying the parent item get the condiments
          $.ajax({
            url:'/get_noun_group_combination',
            type:'get',
            data:{chain_id:chain_id},
            success:function(response){

              var noun_chaining = response[0].noun_chaining;
              $.each(noun_chaining, function (index, el) {

                var stringify_noun_chaining = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(el)); 

                var Qty = stringify_noun_chaining['Qty'];
                var Condiments = stringify_noun_chaining['Condiments'];
                var Price = stringify_noun_chaining['Price'];
                var allow_to_open_condiments = stringify_noun_chaining['allow_to_open_condiments'];
                var condiments_section_id = stringify_noun_chaining['condiments_section_id'];

                $("tbody#tbody_noun_chaining_order").
                append("<tr class='editCondiments'>\
                <td class='condiments_order_quantity'>"+Qty+"</td>\
                <td class='child_item'>*"+Condiments+"</td><td class='total'>"+Price+"</td>\
                <td class='allow_to_open_condiments_conditional' style='display:none;'>"+allow_to_open_condiments+"</td>\
                <td class='condi_section_id' style='display:none;'>"+condiments_section_id+"</td>\
                </tr>");

              });

            }
          });
      }


});
```

Table 1.
[image: table 1]

Table 2.
[image: Table 2]

```js
$('button#add_to_cart').on('click',function () {

    var customer_id = $('#hidden_customer_id').val();

    
    var parent_item =[];
    var parent_amount =[];
    

    //child
    var child_item =[];
    var child_quantity =[];
    var child_amount = [];



    //this is for parent item and amount
    $('#noun_chaining_order').find('tr.condimentParent td.parent_item').each(function(){
        parent_item.push($(this).text());
        
    });

    $('#noun_chaining_order').find('tr.condimentParent td.total').each(function(){
        parent_amount.push($(this).text());
        
    });

    //end

    //this is for child item,amount and quantity
    $('#noun_chaining_order').find('tr.editCondiments td.child_item').each(function(){
        child_item.push($(this).text());
        
    });

    $('#noun_chaining_order').find('tr.editCondiments td.total').each(function(){
        child_amount.push($(this).text());
     
    });

    $('#noun_chaining_order').find('tr.editCondiments td.condiments_order_quantity').each(function(){
        child_quantity.push($(this).text());
        
    });



    $.ajax({

      url: '/insert_wish_list_menu_order',
      type: 'post',

      data: {
        customer_id: customer_id,
        append_customer_noun_order: parent_item,
        append_customer_noun_order_price: parent_amount,
        Qty: child_quantity,
        Item: child_item,
        Cost: child_amount
      },

      success:function(response){
        console.log(response);

        $.ajax({

          url: '/insert_wish_list_menu_belong_condiments',
          type: 'post',

          data: {
            Qty: child_quantity,
            Item: child_item,
            Cost: child_amount
          },

          success:function(response){
            console.log(response);

          },
          error:function(response) {
              console.log(response);
          }

        });

      },
      error:function(response) {
          console.log(response);
      }

    });
    


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <table class="table table-hover upsize_check" id="noun_chaining_order" style="border:none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="" value="" id="hidden_customer_id">
    <thead>
      <tr style="font-size: 15px;  color:white;">
        <th scope="col">Qty</th>
        <th scope="col">Items</th>
        <th scope="col">Price</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody style="font-size:14px;" id="tbody_noun_chaining_order">
      <tr class="condimentParent">
        <td></td>
        <td class="parent_item">$5.00 Extra Crispy 2 Piece Box</td>
        <td class="total">5.00</td>
        <td><button class="removeorderWithCondi btn btn-danger form-control">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="editCondiments">
        <td class="condiments_order_quantity">2</td>
        <td class='child_item'>*Standard</td>
        <td class="total">0.00</td>
        <td class="allow_to_open_condiments_conditional" style="display:none;">Yes</td>
        <td class="condi_section_id" style="display:none;">3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="editCondiments">
        <td class="condiments_order_quantity">2</td>
        <td class='child_item'>*Individual Fries</td>
        <td class="total">0.00</td>
        <td class="allow_to_open_condiments_conditional" style="display:none;">Yes</td>
        <td class="condi_section_id" style="display:none;">2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="editCondiments">
        <td class="condiments_order_quantity">1</td>
        <td class='child_item'>*Buttery Bread</td>
        <td class="total">0.00</td>
        <td class="allow_to_open_condiments_conditional" style="display:none;">No</td>
        <td class="condi_section_id" style="display:none;">4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="editCondiments">
        <td class="condiments_order_quantity">1</td>
        <td class='child_item'>*Chocolate Chip Cookie</td>
        <td class="total">0.00</td>
        <td class="allow_to_open_condiments_conditional" style="display:none;">No</td>
        <td class="condi_section_id" style="display:none;">5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="editCondiments">
        <td class="condiments_order_quantity">1</td>
        <td class='child_item'>*355ml Pepsi</td>
        <td class="total">0.00</td>
        <td class="allow_to_open_condiments_conditional" style="display:none;">No</td>
        <td class="condi_section_id" style="display:none;">6</td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr class="condimentParent" style="background-color:" black="" !important',color:'white="" !important'="" '="">              <td></td><td class="parent_item">BIG CRUNCH Sandwich</td><td class="total">7.29</td>              <td><button class="removeorderWithOutCondi btn btn-danger form-control">              <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button></td></tr>

    </tbody>

  </table>
  <center>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color:#3D0081; border-color:#3D0081;" id="add_to_cart">Click to process the order</button>
  </center>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

> "The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis."

In your code the two requests - the first inserting the parent record into `wish_list_menu_order`, the second inserting the child records into `wish_list_menu_belong_condiments` might run on different MySQL connections are not necessarily run in sequence. Instead of querying for `LAST_INSERT_ID()` on the second call, you should call it after inserting the record into the database and return it as part of the AJAX response.

In your current code, all records would be added to the `wish_list_menu_order` in sequence and after this finishes the child elements would be added. In your best case - only if just one MySQL connection is used - you might get the last inserted ID of the parent table and would use this ID for all inserts into `wish_list_menu_belong_condiments`.

### Possible solution

1. for each insert into `wish_list_menu_order`, perform one AJAX call and return the `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.
2. for each child element, perform another AJAX call inside the outer "parent" loop, providing the result of the previous AJAX call as a parameter.

**Back-end code:**

Inserts to `wish_list_menu_order`:

```php
public function insert_wish_list_menu_order(Request $request)
{
    $customer_id = $request->get('customer_id');
    $append_customer_noun_order = $request->get('append_customer_noun_order');
    $append_customer_noun_order_price = $request->get('append_customer_noun_order_price');
    $now = new DateTime();


    DB::insert('INSERT INTO wish_list_menu_order (customer_id,wish_list_menu_name,wish_list_total_price,wish_created_at) 
    VALUES(?,?,?,?) ', [

        $customer_id,
        $append_customer_noun_order,
        $append_customer_noun_order_price,
        $now,
    ]);

    $last_id_insert = DB::select('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as id FROM wish_list_menu_order');
    return response()->json($last_id_insert);   
}
```

Insert into `wish_list_menu_belong_condiments`:

```php
public function insert_wish_list_menu_belong_condiments(Request $request)
{
    $Qty = $request->get('Qty');
    $Item = $request->get('Item');
    $Cost = $request->get('Cost');
    $ParentId= $request->get('ParentId');

    for ($count = 0; $count < count($Item); $count++) {

        DB::insert('INSERT INTO wish_list_menu_belong_condiments (wish_menu_id,belong_condi_name,belong_condi_qty,belong_condi_price,belong_condi_created) 
        VALUES(?,?,?,?,?) ', [

            $ParentId,
            $Item[$count],
            $Qty[$count],
            $Cost[$count],
            $now,
        ]);
    }

    return response()->json('Successfully Inserted');
}
```

**Front-end code:**

```js
// just for fiddle demo
var orderNumber = 358;
var customer_id = $('#hidden_customer_id').val();

$('#add_to_cart').on('click', function() {

  // reset 
  var orders = [];
  var menu;

  $('#tbody_noun_chaining_order').children('tr').each(function() {
    $row = $(this);
    if ($row.hasClass('condimentParent')) {

      // store a previous menu to the orders array if exists.
      if (menu !== undefined) {
        orders.push(menu);
      }
      menu = {
        'total': $row.find('.total').text(),
        'name': $row.find('.parent_item').text(),
        'condiments': {
          'Item': [],
          'Qty': [],
          'Total': []
        }
      };

    } else if ($row.hasClass('editCondiments')) {
      // row is a condiment, append elements to the previous "menu" variable
      menu.condiments.Item.push($row.find('.child_item').text());
      menu.condiments.Qty.push($row.find('.condiments_order_quantity').text());
      menu.condiments.Total.push($row.find('.total').text());
    }
  });
  if (menu) {
    orders.push(menu);
  }
  storeOrder(orders);
});

function storeOrder(orders) {

  for (var num in orders) {

    // simulate storing the order
    $.ajax('/echo/json', {
      type: 'POST',
      // as the call is asynchronous, make sure to provide all required reference data along with the call.
      context: orders[num].condiments,
      data: {
        'json': '"' + (orderNumber++) + '"',
        'customer_id': customer_id,
        'append_customer_noun_order_price': orders[num].total,
        'append_customer_noun_order': orders[num].name,
      },
      success: function(orderNumber) {
        if (!isNaN(orderNumber)) {
          $.ajax('/echo/json', {
            context: orderNumber,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
              'ParentId': orderNumber,
              'Item': this.Item,
              'Qty': this.Qty,
              'Total': this.Total,
              'json': '{"condimentsCount": ' + this.Item.length + '}'
            },
            success: function(result) {
              $('#result').append('Stored ' + result.condimentsCount + ' condiments for order ' +
                this + '<br />');
            }
          }); // End of condiments save procedure
        }
      }
    }); // End of menu save procedure
  }
}
```

Fiddle showing the mocked front-end part:

https://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/qbhnctre/

**General advise:**

- don't trust any data you receive from the user: a clever user might simply change the price of the condiments or menus inside the HTML before sending it to the server. Load the prices for each item on the server-side instead.
- check your Browser's Web Developer Tools' Console. This will give you early warnings if you are having JS mistakes
- also use the Developer Tools to scan the HTML code your JavaScript creates.

Comment: hi @SaschaM, can you give more explanation for this , hmm can you give example

Comment: @DevGe just added the backend code, I'll need some minutes to add the changed JS code as well. Have a look at the above code in the meantime.

Comment: so i need to create new ajax request?

Comment: @DevGe yes, one AJAX call for each parent record returning the INSERT_ID, a subsequent one for the child elements that use the returned ID as parameter. Also if you want to mention someone in a comment, use "@" followed by the complete user name so they are notified. In my case that still worked as you commented on my own post.

Comment: @Sashcha, why do you remove the for loop in the wish_list_menu_order

Comment: it will retur array string convertion to that

Comment: @DevGe instead of passing along an array of all menus, you would only send one menu to the `insert_wish_list_menu_order()` call. `$append_customer_noun_order` will only contain one number instead of a list of numbers. As I don't have your frontend code, I added an explanation for the frontend part how I would solve it to my code.

Comment: Hi @sascha for clarification, what do you mean one menu to the insert_wsh_list_menu_order(); do you mean for that I only insert 1 item?

Comment: I will share to you how I append the table row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192136/discussion-between-devge-and-sascham78).

Comment: bro. can i ask in our problem how can i empty the push array?

Comment: Sure :-). Easiest would be to use `orders=[]` or `menu.condiments.Item = []` to empty an existing array.

Comment: where should i put that inside of function or in the onclick function?

Comment: or after storeOrder(orders);

Comment: Its all work, but the second insertion it gives 3 items inserted

Comment: Have a look at the above code I posted. Inside the `$('#add_to_cart').click()` routine I already reset the variables using `var orders = [];` and `var menu;`.

Comment: Could you use `var menu = undefined;` to really make sure the variable is set to an undefined state?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192379/discussion-between-devge-and-sascham78).